# mongodb nodejs store value outside connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need a way to store value outside mongoDB connect call:

```
read(object) {
    let result
    MongoClient.connect(this.url, function (err, db) {
        if (err!=null){
            result = err;
        } else {
            db.collection(object.collection).find(object.field).toArray(function(err, docs) {
                assert.equal(err, null);  
                db.close();       
                result = docs; 
            }); 
        }
    }); 
    return result
}
```

When i call this method, which is part of a class, return is called before result assignment, as normal.
Example: `console.log(read(obj))` returns undefined

The idea is to store value in a variable and return might wait until connect terminate.

Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Use [Promice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for that

Comment: it could be an idea.. but if i use Promise, i need to extract result of a promise (in thenable call)

Answer (score 0):

Without promise:

Call return inside find and err function:

```
read(object) {
    let result
    MongoClient.connect(this.url, function (err, db) {
        if (err!=null){
            result = err;
            return result; //here
        } else {
            db.collection(object.collection).find(object.field).toArray(function(err, docs) {
                assert.equal(err, null);  
                db.close();       
                result = docs;
                return result;  // here
            }); 
        }
    });
}
```

Or set a timeout for return with enough time to wait for other process to end:

```
read(object) {
    let result
    MongoClient.connect(this.url, function (err, db) {
        if (err!=null){
            result = err;
        } else {
            db.collection(object.collection).find(object.field).toArray(function(err, docs) {
                assert.equal(err, null);  
                db.close();       
                result = docs; 
            }); 
        }
    }); 
    setTimeout(function(){ return result}, 3000);   // 3secs
}
```

Comment: there is no difference, because if i call method, it returns undefined

Comment: then the problem is you are assigning undefined val to result, i answered based on what you asked "When i call this method, which is part of a class, return is called before result assignment"

Comment: it's absolutely normal!! the execution of a connect methos is async!! i need to handle this behavior

Answer (score 0):

With [Promise](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiV473eqKrXAhUL1BoKHblLA2sQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fit%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FPromise&usg=AOvVaw2Jjg1aia2yKLh3bfMwkmRr) you can try the following:

```
function read(object) {
    let result
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(this.url, function (err, db) {
            if (err!=null){
                reject(err);
            } else {
                db.collection(object.collection).find(object.field).toArray(function(err, docs) {
                    db.close();   
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(docs);                                        
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
    });
}

// then you can call the function and use the result like this
read(obj).then(docs => {
    console.log(docs);
})
.catch(err => {
    // handle error
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: yes, it works! But i need to store value of docs (or err) outside thenable call!

Comment: I don't know the context of your application. You can store the result as you want once the Promise is resolved. You can define a result variable outside the read function and assign the result (docs or err) to that variable. Or if you have some kind of singleton/service assign that result to a variable inside the service so it is accessible to other parts of your applications. It depends on what you are trying to do.